# При записи данных файл запись обрывается не выдавая исключений

Tags: c#, файлы, потоки-данных, вывод, теги

Имею код, который по пути к папке, берёт все мп3 файлы, считывает теги исполнителя и название, и выводит их в текстовый файл построчно. Вроде бы всё работает, но буквально под конец ~(1180\1200) обрывает запись посредине строки и заканчивает исполнение не доходя до конца списка файлов и даже не дописывая исполнителя и название до конца.

Скр*птонит - Цепи (feat. 104)(ОК)

Скр*птонит - Я не <-(???Так не должно быть)

Ну и вопрос собственно, что могло пойти не так?

КОД:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using TagLib;
//using File = TagLib.File;

namespace mp3ToSpotify
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            //Директория с музыкой
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\Music");

            //Экземляр потока файлов
            FileStream fs = null;

            //Экземпляр класса для ображениям к тегам
            TagLib.File tagFile = null;

            //Создаем поток данных в указаный файл
            fs = new FileStream(@"F:\music10.txt", FileMode.Create);

            var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
            
            //За каждую итерацию мы перебираем каждый последующий файл, подставляя путь к каждому последующему файлу в
            //tagFile. После обращаясь уже к самому файлу берём тег исполнителя и названия песни и вписываем в файл построчно.
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles("*.mp3"))
                try
                {
                    tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(file.FullName);
                    sw.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", string.Join(", ", tagFile.Tag.Performers), tagFile.Tag.Title);
                }
                catch (CorruptFileException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
                    throw;
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Finish!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Совет дня: "Написали - закройте файл."*

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(...)) {
  using (var sw = new StreamWriter(...)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Про закрытие файла - согласен, но к сожаление код приложенный не пойму:)

Comment: @rhapsodyy Хорошо, тогда просто добавьте в конце `sw.Close();fs.Close();`.

Comment: @rhapsodyy что именно не понятно в коде? Оператор [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)?

Comment: _Совет дня: не советуйте использовать `.Close()` без конструкции `try-finally`._ Это плохая практика, которая пустит все старания коту под хвост при возникновении исключения.

Comment: @aepot Если выбросилось исключение, то всё-равно данные будут не полные - что-то пошло не так )  Но в целом лучше `using` в любом случае конечно использовать

Comment: @aepot Не встречался в своей учебной практике с такими конструкциями, этот оператор мне знаком только как подключатель System и прочих библ:)

Comment: @rhapsodyy `using` как подключатель пространства имен и `using` как декоратор `IDisposable` классов - разные операторы. По возможности используйте его со всеми реализующими `IDisposable` классами, особенно с теми, которые работают с сетью и файловой системой, внимательно читайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Comment: @aepot Не будет сложно показать как это нужно реализовать в моем коде? Это мне сильно поможет в осмыслении:)

Comment: @rhapsodyy `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)) { ваш код, использующий sw }`.